# Problem ESP32 send data to Google Sheet through Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, esp32, arduino-esp32

At first, my question is from my little project IoT. Purpose, using ESP32 send data to Google Sheet through Google App Script.

The ESP32 task is to take two random numbers and pass them to Google Sheet through Google App Script (Web App) by http.

My problem is, I can insert data to Google Sheet only 3-4 records, after that connection between ESP32 and Google App Script has failed everytime. I am not sure about the problem.

My codes has 2 parts, first is for ESP32 (Arduino IDE), and second is for Google App Script

First part code is below, it is very simple.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
String t;
const char* host = "script.google.com";
const int httpsPort = 443;
const char* ssid = "MY_SSID";
const char* pass = "MY_SSID_PW";
String GAS_ID = "GAS_ID";
String GAS_Sheet = "dht_data";
WiFiClientSecure client;
long now = millis();
long lastMeasure = 0;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200); delay(500);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    Serial.print("\nConnecting");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.print("\nSuccessfully connected to : "); Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("\nIP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println();
    client.setInsecure();
}
void loop() {
    now = millis();
    if (now - lastMeasure > 30000) {
        lastMeasure = now;
        float ValueSensor1 = random(2000, 4000) / 100.0;
        float ValueSensor2 = random(6000, 8000) / 100.0;
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("\ntemperature = "); Serial.print(ValueSensor1, 1);
        Serial.print("\thumidity = "); Serial.print(ValueSensor2, 1);
        Serial.println();
        sendData(ValueSensor1, ValueSensor2);
    }
}
void sendData(float SValue1, float SValue2) {
    Serial.println("==========");
    Serial.print("connecting to "); Serial.println(host);
    //---- Connect to Google host
    if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
        return;
    }
    //---- Post Data
    String url;
    url += "/macros/s/" + GAS_ID + "/exec?";
    url += "id=" + String(GAS_Sheet);
    url += "&temperature=" + String(SValue1, 2);
    url += "&humidity=" + String(SValue2, 2);
    Serial.print("requesting URL: "); Serial.println(url);
    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
            "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
            "User-Agent: BuildFailureDetectorESP8266\r\n" +
            "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
    Serial.println("request sent");
    //---- Wait Echo
    while (client.connected()) {
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
        if (line == "\r") {
            Serial.println("headers received");
            break;
        }
    }
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (line.startsWith("{\"state\":\"success\"")) {
        Serial.println("ESP-32/Arduino CI successfull!");
    } else {
        Serial.println("ESP-32/Arduino CI has failed");
    }
    Serial.print("reply was : ");
    Serial.println(line);
    Serial.println("closing connection");
    Serial.println("==========");
    Serial.println();
}
```

Second part code is below,

```
function doGet(e){
    // open the spreadsheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    // use the 'id' parameter to differentiate between sheets
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter["id"]);

    // extract headers
    // getRange accepts row, col, number_of_rows and num_of_cols as argument
    // getLastColumn returns the position of the last column that has content
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    // store the position of the last row
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
    var col = 0;
    var d = new Date();
    for (i in headers){
        // loop through the headers and if a parameter name matches the header name insert the value
        if (headers[i] == "Timestamp") {
            val = d.toDateString() + ", " + d.toLocaleTimeString();
        } else {
            val = e.parameter[headers[i]];
        }
        // append data to the last row
        cell.offset(lastRow, col).setValue(val);
        col++;
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('success');
}
```

What is the cause of problem? and How can I solve it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: As my guess, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: @Jatu Tung, please edit the question to include the output from your ESP32, including any crashing/booting messages. We need to know how this failed, not just that it failed. There are many different things that can go wrong; the output will help narrow down what "fail" means.

Answer (score 1):

@Jatu Tung I think you forgot to close the previous connection before opening another connection. Just try adding `client.stop();` to your sendData function after sending you data. It should work as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my guess. From `My problem is, I can insert data to Google Sheet only 3-4 records, after that connection between ESP32 and Google App Script has failed everytime. I am not sure about the problem.`, I was worried about the frequency of sending the data to Web Apps. I thought that when the data is continuously sent to Web Apps, such an error might occur. So in this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, I reduced the process cost of your Google Apps Script for Web Apps, and add the LockService.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  const lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(350000)) {
    try {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(e.parameter["id"]);
      var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      var d = new Date();
      var values = headers.map(h => h == "Timestamp" ? d.toDateString() + ", " + d.toLocaleTimeString() : e.parameter[h]);
      sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, values.length).setValues([values]);
    } catch (e) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
      return ContentService.createTextOutput('success');
    }
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("timeout");
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- In my recent report, when the process cost of the script of Web Apps is low, about 60 concurrent accesses can be done for the Web Apps. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c2f3fccabbf4906a18fdc38463982f31) But, in the case of the process cost of your situation, I have never measured it. So I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution to your issue.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Concurrent Writing to Google Spreadsheet using Form](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c2f3fccabbf4906a18fdc38463982f31)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)